# Changing the Data Type of an excel column using XLSX NPM package

Tags: excel, xlsx

I am trying to convert JSON to sheet in xlsx using sheet_to_json function as shown below

```js
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const data = [
    {
        "Employee Id": 355618,
        "Date Of Birth": "2020-02-27",
        "Account Number": "0000202020202121123"
    },
    {
        "Employee Id": 356578768,
        "Date Of Birth": "2021-02-27",
        "Account Number": "0000202020202121123"
    }
]
const fileName = 'result/test8.xlsx';
const WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
const WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
WorkSheet.columns = [
    { header: 'Employee Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
    { header: 'Date Of Birth', key: 'dob', width: 32},
    { header: 'Account Number', key: 'account', width: 10 }
];
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(WorkBook, WorkSheet, 'test');
XLSX.writeFile(WorkBook, fileName);
```

After converting the json to sheet , in my excel the date field is coming as a string but I need it to be of DATE TYPE so that I can apply formatting and can add date filtering on the excel sheet

Actual Result :: [image: Data is getting considered as String type]

But what I need/ expected result is ::
[image: should be considered as Date Type]

Is there a way to do that ??
Can someone help on this ??